# NAT'ing a specific port not working on Ubuntu, works correctly on Fedora

Tags: iptables, nat, firewalld

We have previously been running Fedora instances but for a few reasons we have needed to move over to Ubuntu based distros.

Previously, we have used the following firewalld rules in order to NAT specific ports and it worked flawlessly.

```
sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 net.ipv4.conf.ens5.send_redirects=0
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 587 -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now when we apply the same rules to firewalld on Ubuntu (22.04), they do not seem to have any effect. Our requirement is to only NAT specific ports.

The only difference we noticed between the fedora and ubuntu boxes was that the interface name changed from eth0 to ens5. We made that change in our command.

We have checked that they are being applied to the correct zone.

Any tips on where we may be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.